# Django and Javascript: dependent dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am basically new in using Javascript and Django.

This is my script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#source").change(function() {
                var el = $(this);

                var reg = [];
                var name = [];

                {% for item in city %}

                    reg.push({{ item.reg }});
                    name.push({{ item.name }});

                {% endfor %}

                var a = getElementById("status").length;

                for(val i = 0; i<a; i++){
                    if(el.val() == reg[i]){
                        $("#status").append("<option id = "+ reg[i] +">" + name[i] + "</option>");
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my form:

```
<form method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select id="source" name="source">
            <option>-----</option>
            {% for item in region %}
                <option id = {{ item.id }}>{{ item.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <select id="status" name="status">
            <option>-----</option>
        </select>

        <select id="3">

            <option>-----</option>
            {% for item in zip %}
                <option id = {{ item.cit }}>{{ item.num }}</option>
            {% endfor %}

        </select>
    </form>
```

What I want to achieve is that the second dropdown box will display the contents under the selected item in the first dropdown box. I actually don't understand what am I doing wrong because it doesn't show any result whenever I load it, and there are no errors displayed too. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The django template tags are already finished rendering when the page finishes loading, so when your javascript starts to execute, there's no `for` loop anymore.

Comment: If you're new to Javascript I would personally suggest gaining a level of comfortability with the language before using any Frameworks or APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this part:

```
            {% for item in city %}

                reg.push({{ item.reg }});
                name.push({{ item.name }});

            {% endfor %}
```

Unless `{{ item.name }}` evaluates to quoted values like `'cardiff'`, it'll render like:

```
name.push(cardiff)
```

And that would be undefined. Maybe with some quotes:

```
name.push('{{ item.name }}')
```

Also, shouldn't the for loop be like this ?

```
for(val i = 0; i<reg.length; i++){
```

There is also a typo in `{{ item.cit }}`.

You should also inspect and paste the generated HTML and JS.

!!! Pro-tip: You should use the JS debugger from your browser !!!

Comment: I tried that and it did not work but i found a solution. It is almost the same as your answer by doing it like this `var reg = [{% for item in city %}"{{ item.reg }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];`